# Mining Bitcoin heats up my Computer. why?

Tags: bitcoin-core, mining-hardware, currencies

I am Trying to mining bit coins from last 1 year. but every time i turn on the mining it slows down my computer and heat it up very badly that it eventually stops working some times.
How To get rid of this?
Help Me Please.

Comment: Mining uses your computer's computation power - the more it uses, the more yiu're rewarded. If you don't want it to slow down your system, don't do it. Furthermore, Bitcoin cannot be profitably mined on home computer hardware since 2013 or so; you need specialized ASIC-based hardware instead. If you're mining today, it's either an altcoin (which is off topic here), or a scam.

Answer (score 3):

All of the energy that is used in any computation eventually leaves the hardware as thermal energy. Bitcoin mining is an energy intensive computational process, so one of the by-products of it is thermal energy (heat). If you want to stop generating heat, you'll have to stop mining (or figure out how to dissipate the heat more efficiently).

Keep in mind that bitcoin mining is only profitable using specialized ASIC hardware (that generates a lot of heat). Mining bitcoin with your laptop/PC will just use up electricity (and generate heat), without any real chance of doing enough work for you to receive a reward.